# spark mllib memory error on svd (single machine)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a large data file (around 4 GB) and I am analyzing it using spark on a single pc.

```
scala> x
res29: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix = org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix@5a86096a

scala> x.numRows
res27: Long = 302529

scala> x.numCols
res28: Long = 1828
```

When I try to compute the principal components I get a memory error:

```
scala> val pc: Matrix = x.computePrincipalComponents(2)

     15/03/30 14:55:22 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned shuffle 1
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at breeze.linalg.svd$.breeze$linalg$svd$$doSVD_Double(svd.scala:92)
        at breeze.linalg.svd$Svd_DM_Impl$.apply(svd.scala:39)
        at breeze.linalg.svd$Svd_DM_Impl$.apply(svd.scala:38)
        at breeze.generic.UFunc$class.apply(UFunc.scala:48)
        at breeze.linalg.svd$.apply(svd.scala:22)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computePrincipalComponents(RowMatrix.scala:380)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have more RAM than Spark currently utilizes, you can try to increase the Java heap size with the command-line option `--driver-memory 8g` (assuming "local" mode here, in which the calculation is done by the driver program). Default is only 512m.